# latex equation writing problem

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Hi everyone, I would like to write following equations in the Latex. Could you please someone help me?

Comment: Could you post here what you've done so far? With which symbol/part exactly have you got a problem?

Answer (score 7):

Something like the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
  F^{-1}_{\text{Risk}_m} (\text{stress level}_m) = \num{0.995}
  \text{ with }
  \text{Risk}_m \sim
  N(\mu_m, \sigma_m^2)
  \text{ for }
  m = 1, \dots, 5
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And the in text version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  $F^{-1}_{\text{Risk}_m} (\text{stress level}_m) = \num{0.995}$
  with $\text{Risk}_m \sim N(\mu_m, \sigma_m^2)$
  for $m = 1, \dots, 5$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  F^{1}_{Risk_{m}}(stress~{} level_{m}) &= 0.995 ~{}with~{}Risk_{m}^{~}N
  (\$\mu_m,(\sigma_{m})^2\$) ~{}for m = 1,...,5\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: required equation]

Comment: This is wrong in the sense that e.g. `Risk` in math mode is interpreted as the four "variables" `R`, `i`, `s` and `k`, giving wrong spacing etc. Same for `for m` which LaTeX "sees" as four variables, hence the missing space before the `m`. See @Heiko's answer for the correct way to typeset text inside math environments.

Comment: @nordev is right, although I understand that you may have been trying to replicate the original as closely as possible. In this case, though, you should use `\mathit{}` if you want the words to be italic because this will give the correct kerning between the letters. Better still you could use `\textit{}` and you wouldn't need to insert manual spaces. I'm also not sure why you're using an `align*` environment - you're not aligning anything. You should really use `\dots` rather than `...` - it gives correct spacing. Also, is there any reason why you prefer `~{} ` to a simple `\ `?

Comment: thank you for your help, but I still have problem

Comment: Your comment doesn't help to people who try to help you. You ask for typing equation in LaTeX and you got adequate answer and helpful comments. So, you should be far more specific, what is still your problem and show, what you try yourself so far.